# Two different assignments for interrupt registers in ATmega328. Why first one doesn't work?

Tags: c, interrupt, atmega

I was initializing registers for overflow interrupt in Atmega328.

I first started with the following initialization but it didn't work.

```
TCCR1B |= 0x05; 
TIMSK1 |= 0x01;
```

Then I tried the following code instead:

```
TCCR1B = (TCCR1B & B11111000) | 0x05;
TIMSK1 = (TIMSK1 & B11111110) | 0x01;
```

The first two lines of code didn't invoke the ISR but the last two lines of code did! 
How? Do it have to do somthing with Read Modify Write?

Comment: The former does not *clear* the bit 1

Comment: But we do not want to clear the bit 1. We want it to be set to enable the Overflow vector

Comment: You are doing different things with TCCR1B. The second one clear Bit 1 the first not.

Comment: @Bhuvnesh Bits are counted beginning with 0 from the LSB, not 1.

Comment: Oh sorry I just slipped my mind. Yes I know the LSB stuff. @Mike TCCR1B has a default value of zero always(as indicated by the datasheet of armega 328 on page136)

Comment: Please write the whole code, probably issue is not in those two lines.

Answer (score 0):

The two pieces of code are not equivalent. Assume that `TCCR1B` has an initial value of `0xFF`

```
TCCR1B |= 0x05; // this will result in a value of `0xFF`.

TCCR1B = (TCCR1B & B11111000) | 0x05;  // This will result in a value of '0xFD'
```

Comment: No, in the second case the register is not written two times. The register is read, then the read value gets its bits 2 down to 0 cleared (BTW, that's 3 bits, not 4), then the result gets its bit 2 and 0 set, and finally this is written into the register. See, 1 read and 1 write. You would have been right if the code were `TCCR1B &= 0xF8; TCCR1B |= 0x05;`.

Comment: @Rishikesh Raje TCCR1B has a default value of zero always(as indicated by the datasheet of armega 328 on page136)

Comment: never trust the default values in the datasheet.

Comment: In that case, won't this first code be better than the the second one? TCCR1B = 0x05;  Rather than writing : TCCR1B = (TCCR1B & B11111000) | 0x05;

Comment: @Bhuvnesh - In the second example, the values of the 5 MSbits are preserved. Only the value of the last 3 LSbits are changed. Regarding default values, it gives the value at reset. There may be changes to the value after that, by you or by the start up and initialization code.